# using python properties inside __init__?

Tags: python, properties

I have a class using several property()'s. Modifying a text's font, size, or string, etc.. will require a re-render of a surface to cache.

What is the recommended way to call a class's own property(), inside **init** ? The problem is that the variable has not been set, at the time I want to call @property DrawText.text

If I directly set ._text, it runs:

```
class DrawText(object):
    """works, Except ignores text.setter"""
    def __init__(self):
        # self.text = "fails" # would fail if here
        self._text = "default"
        self.text = "works"
    @property 
    def text(self):
        '''plain-text string property'''
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        if self._text == text: return       
        self._text = text
        self.dirty = True # .. code re-creates the surface
```

This also runs, and is closer, **but will it work with multiple instances, using different data?**

```
class DrawText(object):
    """works, Except ignores text.setter"""
    def __init__(self):
        DrawText.text = "default"
        self.text = "works"
    @property 
    def text(self):
        '''plain-text string property'''
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        if self._text == text: return       
        self._text = text
        self.dirty = True # .. code re-creates the surface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **text** property, you could write this:

```
try:
    return self._text
except AttributeError:
    self._text = None
return self._text
```

Then there is no need to set any internal attributes before (or on) instantiation.

Comment: Does testing AttributeError ever have a performance penalty, when the property is read frequently?

Comment: Generally, try/except blocks are cheap if you expect them hardly ever to fail, but expensive if they are expected to raise the exception frequently.

Comment: Python carries no huge performance penalty for exception handling. In fact this style of programming is actually encouraged see "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission". The performance is usually degraded when the exception is actually thrown very often, but in your case it will only be thrown once, since the attribute is set then.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because the backing field `self._text` is not defined yet when the setter is called the first time.

Simple initialize it on the class level:

```
class DrawText(object):
    _text = None
    # your code here
```

Another solution (in your case) would be simply setting both the backing field of the property and the dirty flag manually since a new object is probably considered dirty anyway.